# How to add markers in Google Maps and save them properly?

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a Map of Google integrated in my app, where I added 4 markers for testing purposes. All's fine. I added the markers using Latitude/Longtitude coordinates. 
Now, I want the user to add a marker inside the map and I want to save these added markers inside the map. So, if the user restarts the app and opens the map again, I want the added markers to be saved and to be seen there.

How can I do this? Is this even possible? Any tips are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You won't exactly be saving the markers, but there are plenty of ways to save the data you need to *recreate* the marker (e.g. the lat/lng coordinates, the marker title, etc).

The easiest is probably to use `SharedPreferences`: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

You could also use a database, write a file to the device's storage, or many other options.

Comment: I see, thank you. It is very likely that the user adds new markers by using street names. Therefore I have to use a Map method that gives me the lat/Ing coordinates of the street  names. Is that possible too ? Because I don't think that the user will add markers by using coordinates :)